# Matlab toolbox (Windows) for Sick lasers?

Tags: laser, matlab

Does anybody know where I can get a matlab toolbox or functions to work with a SICK laser-scanner (Windows OS)? I'm using a SICK-LDRS2110 with ethernet cable, but SOPAS software does not allow me to program recording times and other specific tasks. Any tips are more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the protocol specification, which is very well documented and easy to implement. Instead of using the sicktoolbox, I suggest writing your own driver, which meets your recommendations. This gives you more control over the performance, because you can just ignore (for you) useless commands.

Answer (score 0):

http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/ but I can't vouch for it; at my company we've coded our own drivers from scratch.